# Linq Divide Object into multiple object by Property

Tags: c#, linq

I am just wondering if there is a way to split a list item into two list items based on an object property using C# LINQ.

For example:

```
{
  "ItemName": "Test Item",
  "SubItemName": [
    {
      "Sub-Item-1",
      "Sub-Item-2",
    }
  ]
}
```

how to split this object by subItemName like:

```
{
  "ItemName": "Test Item Name",
  "SubItemName": "Sub-Item-1"
},
{
  "ItemName": "Test Item Name",
  "SubItemName": "Sub-Item-2",  
}
```

Comment: Can you show up the c# code you have so far so we can tell where you are getting stuck?

Comment: Always try to post a working code. You just showed us some JSON. How could we give a working code to you? (I tried to give one, below!)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is `SelectMany`. Let's look at a simple example:

```
class C
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<string> Subs { get; set; }
}
```

Now let's make a bunch of them.

```
var cs = new List<C> {
  new C { Name = "Alice", Subs = new List<string> { "Orange", "Green" }},
  new C { Name = "Bobby", Subs = new List<string> { "Red", "Blue" }}
}
```

That is, we have

```
Alice
  Orange
  Green
Bobby
  Red
  Blue
```

You want a new list that is

```
Alice
  Orange
Alice
  Green
Bobby
  Red
Bobby
  Blue
```

Right?

Any time you want to "flatten" a list-of-lists you use SelectMany.  Either in comprehension form:

```
var query = 
  from c in cs
  from s in c.Subs
  select new C { Name = c.Name, Subs = new List<string> { s } };
```

Or in fluent form

```
var query = 
  cs.SelectMany(
    c => c.Subs,
    (c, s) => new C { Name = c.Name, Subs = new List<string> { s } });
```

which as you can see has the same structure, just a little harder to read.

If you then need a list out the other end:

```
var newList = query.ToList();
```

And you're done.

Comment: Hi Eric, Thank you so much for your help. Almost i finished my query and i solved most of them with your help. What if there are two Orange then it should be like;

<br/>
```
Alice<br/>
  Orange<br/>
  Orange<br/>
  Count : 2<br/>
Alice<br/>
  Green<br/>
  Count : 1<br/>
Bobby<br/>
  Red<br/>
  Count : 1<br/>
Bobby<br/>
  Blue<br/>
  Count : 1<br/>
<br/>

I mean that Eric

Comment: @Cemal: Then what you want to do is in the `from s in c.Subs` instead what you want to do is "`(from g in c.Subs group by...`" and turn the collection of subs into a *collection of groups of the same thing*. That gives you a *sequence of groups* where the element you've grouped on is `Key`, and the number of such elements is `Count()`, and you can then achieve your goal from there.

Answer (score 1):

A single item:

```
var item = new {
  ItemName = "Test Item",
  SubItemName = new string[]
    {
      "Sub-Item-1",
      "Sub-Item-2",
    }
};
```

I guess you have a collection of such items:

```
var items = new [] { item, /* other items */ };
```

And here is the LINQ:

```
var result =
    from i in items
    from si in i.SubItemName
    select new 
    {
        ItemName = i.ItemName,
        SubItemName = si
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

**use the LINQ .Select() Method on the collection**

You can use the `.Select()` Method to project the things in your `SubItems` collection into a completely new form.

Since you didn't post the code of what you have so far, I will answer in general. Check out this code. :

```
public class WhateverYouHaveThere
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<string> SubItemName { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //the thing you have
        var theThingYouHave = new WhateverYouHaveThere() { 
            Name = "Test Item",
            SubItemName = new List<string>() {
                "Sub-Item 1", 
                "SubItem 2" } 
        };

        //split the thing into a new list
        var theResultingListYouWant = theThingYouHave.SubItemName
            .Select(p => new WhateverYouHaveThere() { 
                Name = theThingYouHave.Name, 
                SubItemName = new List<string>() { p } }
            ).ToList();
    }
}
```

please accept as answer if that worked for you

greetings, Mike